# wifi-direct(wifiP2p) multiple group connection

Tags: android

I want to know whether 2 group owners of wifiP2p can connect with each other?Say there are 2 group owners A and B both with one/more clients.Now if A tries to connect to B or vice versa,is it possible?
In that case if yes then what happens to their group members(clients)?I mean if B is somehow connected to A then clients of B are still connected to B or they move up to A or connection drops between B and it's clients?I have read previous blogs regarding the same but none is conclusive.Pl help

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that multiple network connection is not possible that is two group owners will simply not be able to connect with each other.They can only send a invitation request.Let me know if I m wrong.Tested it on 4 mobiles.